# Text correlation in Python

Tags: python

I am analyzing a survey that has "Yes" or "No" questions. I want to find the strongest correlation between questions and the answers. For example, if someone answers "Yes" to Question 1 what is the correlation that they would also respond "Yes" to Question 2? Could it be as easy as assigning each answer to a numeric value (0 + 1)? I hope that I made this clear enough.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it's that simple.

Comment: use `PCA` to know the correlation between any two questions

Comment: The mutual information between two questions might be what you are looking for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to calculate probability I presume you have a decent population of people who have taken the survey. You can use this data, and simple conditional probability formula to get the information you seek.

presuming that P(A) > 0 we know that P(B|A) = P(A ^ B) / P(A)

which is to say, that the probability of B given A is equal to the probability of A and B over the probability of A. If 10% of your survey takers answered YES to question1 and question2 (A ^ B), and 50% of your survey takers answered YES to question1 (A), then the probability that a random person answering YES to question2 given that they have answered YES to question1 = .1/.5 = .2 or 20%. This all presumes that you know exactly what proportion of people answered YES to problem 1, and how what proportion of people answered YES to both problems 1 and 2.